# function parameter that is pointer to another function

Tags: c++, templates

This is a more specific question based on a question I asked earlier...

If I have a function that takes two parameters (one required, one optional):

1. an STL container such as a vector
2. an "optional" comparison function that serves as a relational overload and returns the maximum value, whatever that is, in the vector...

Code:

```
template <typename Type>
Type FindMax (std::vector<Type> &myVec, int (*cmp)(Type one, Type two) = CallBack)
/.../
```

WHAT exactly, does the "int (*cmp)(Type one...)" say to the compiler?  I want it to say, here's a function to use when comparing two of type Type...ie when using the relational operators <, >, =, etc.  If no function is supplied by the user then use the default, otherwise, use what the user provides...

What exactly does the (*cmp)(Type one, Type two) say?  Here's a pointer to a function that takes two parameters Type one and Type two?  Is there any significance as to what comes after the *, ie could I write (*titsmagee)(Type one, Type two)?  I'm assuming the naming convention is to help future readers?

For this to work with a "struct" does anything specific to the potential comparisons to be made need to be stored within said struct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int (*cmp)(Type one, Type two)
```

The parameter named `cmp` is a pointer to a function returning `int` that takes two parameters of type `Type`.

```
struct Foo
{
   int x;
};
int compare(Foo x, Foo y)
{
   return (x.x == y.x) ? 0 : (x.x > y.x ? 1 : -1);
}

std::vector<Foo> vec;

FindMax<Foo>(vec, &compare);
```

You need `cmp` so you can call the comparison function inside `FindMax`:

```
template <typename Type>
Type FindMax (std::vector<Type> &myVec, int (*cmp)(Type one, Type two) = CallBack)
{
    //whatever loop
    max = cmp(myVec[i],myVec[j]) >= 0 ? myVec[i] : myVec[j];
}
```

**EDIT** Breaking down the return:

```
return (x.x == y.x) ? 0 : (x.x > y.x ? 1 : -1);
```

`?:` is the ternary conditional operator.

```
condition ? expression1 : expression2
```

*returns* (loosely speaking) expression1 if `condition` is true, expression2 otherwise.

So what that means is:

```
if (x.x == y.x) 
   return 0; 
else 
   if (x.x > y.x) 
       return 1; 
   else 
       return -1;
```

It's what you expect the comparison function to do. Return `0` for equality, `1` if the first element is bigger than the second, and `-1` for the inverse.

**EDIT 2**

```
struct Foo
{
   int x;
};
//Foo has a member x.
Foo f;
//Create a Foo object called f.
f.x;
//Access the member x of the object
```

Comment: that makes sense and I can see partly where I've gone wrong.  I'm not familiar with the way you wrote a few things.  Could you clarify or at least tell me the name of the syntax so that I can read about it?  Particularly: "return(x.x == y.x)" How does the x.x, y.x work?  What does the "? 0 :" mean?...  Basically, if you could break down that "return" line that would be HUGE.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  That helps a ton.  Can someone explain what the "x.x and y.x" is?

Comment: damnit, can't believe I didn't see that.  You're right, basic.  It was that both the instance and the variable were the same name...it threw me.  I was thinking, "why is the same variable getting called twice?!"  Thanks!